# How to assign proportional space for gridview columns on window maximize and restore down

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a wpf project I am working on how to resize my gridview inside a listview.

Grid setup

```
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="144"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="136"/>               
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="93"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Here is my ListView

```
       <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="view" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged" Loaded="ListView_Loaded">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test" 
                                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test2" 
                                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test3" 
                                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Code added to remove the unwanted column generated by listview

```
    private void ListView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       UpdateColumnsWidth(sender as ListView);
   }

   private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       UpdateColumnsWidth(sender as ListView);
   }

   // To remove the last empty column created by Listview
   private void UpdateColumnsWidth(ListView listView)
   {
       var gridView = listView.View as GridView;
       if (gridView != null)
       {
           int autoFillColumnIndex = gridView.Columns.Count - 1;
           if (double.IsNaN(listView.ActualWidth))
               listView.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
           double remainingSpace = gridView.Columns.Where((t, i) => i != autoFillColumnIndex).Aggregate(listView.ActualWidth, (current, t) => current - t.ActualWidth);
           gridView.Columns[autoFillColumnIndex].Width = remainingSpace >= 0 ? remainingSpace : 0;
       }
```

[image]

Now the problem I have is the last column takes up larger space which i didnt assign for it. I want all my columns to have a proportional space when i do window resize. But right now when i expand the last column takes a lot of space.

Comment: did you try setting columns Width = "1*"?

Comment: @Dilshod I updated with the post with my grid set up

Comment: I see your code, but did you set all the columns to "1*" ?

Comment: @Dilshod if you are refering  to ColumnDefinition yes but ...the result is the same but GridViewColumn Width can't take "*" ...last column still takes lots of space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is explicitly setting one column to take all remaining space. Instead, you need to set them all to the same value, the `ListView` width divided by the number of columns:

```
if (double.IsNaN(listView.ActualWidth))
    listView.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

double colWidth = listView.ActualWidth / gridView.Columns.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Columns.Count; ++i)
    gridView.Columns[i].Width = colWidth;
```

Comment: I don't understand why am I blocked from asking question??

Comment: I don't work for SO, but I imagine the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans